# When is "Christ in you" revealed in a believer?

Tags: john, colossians

In Colossians 1:25-27, Paul was given the ministry to the Gentiles to help them see "Christ in you, the hope of glory," and indicates that he strives to help them to this knowledge. *Is Christ already in them, and it takes time to acknowledge it?* Is that why Paul strove by the Spirit, because it isn't easily grasped?

In John 14:21-13, Jesus tells us that if we keep His Word, then He will manifest Himself to us. He and the Father will come and make their home in us. *Does this imply that Christ is not in us upon salvation and comes later, or is the keeping of the Word a means to help us acknowledge the Christ already inside?* My current impression is that Christ is seen in us obeying the Father when we keep the Word in love toward Christ (with the flesh crucified); we are imitating His own life and He comes to fill us with His own.

When is "Christ in you" revealed in a believer? The above indicates that the Spirit informs the believer by illumination.

Comment: Are you asking when Christ in you is revealed to you, or to someone else?

Answer (score 1):

Paul wrote plainly in Rom 8:9

> 9 You, however, are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if in fact the Spirit of God dwells in you. **Anyone who does not have the Spirit of Christ does not belong to him.** 10 But if Christ is in you, although the body is dead because of sin, the Spirit is life because of righteousness. 11 **If the Spirit of him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, he who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through his Spirit who dwells in you.** (Rom. 8:9–11, ESV)

Rom. 8:11 also makes it clear that the Spirit in the person raised that person from the dead.

In chapters 1-8 Paul is presenting the Gospel.

> 16 For I am not ashamed of the gospel, for it is the power of God for salvation to everyone who believes, to the Jew first and also to the Greek. 17 For in it the righteousness of God is revealed from faith for faith, as it is written, “The righteous shall live by faith.” (Rom. 1:16–17, ESV)

Paul wrote his letter about 57-58 A.D. and first went to Rome around 60 A.D. Thus, it preceded his going there.  How many new Christians are fluent in Christian theology?

Paul was apostle to the Gentiles.

> On the contrary, when they saw that I [Paul] had been entrusted with the gospel to the uncircumcised, just as Peter had been entrusted with the gospel to the circumcised 8 (for he who worked through Peter for his apostolic ministry to the circumcised worked also through me for mine to the Gentiles)(Gal. 2:7–8, ESV)

> 13 Now I am speaking to you Gentiles. Inasmuch then as I am an apostle to the Gentiles, I magnify my ministry (Rom. 11:13, ESV)

Thus, Paul as apostle to the Gentiles strove to make known the theology of the Gospel to the Gentiles.  Romans was the most thorough because he had not yet been there in person to speak to them.  Galatians will give you an idea of why Paul had to strive because some were telling the Gentiles they had to keep the Law of Moses.

The Colossians didn't have the New Testament.  They had Paul, the Apostles, and the Old Testament, that had been translated into Greek (LXX). Today "Christ in you" is revealed to a believer when reading the New Testament.

Comment: Why did Paul have to strive to get this known to the Gentiles? (Colossians 1:25-27)